# Installing 2 Google Analytics trackers to amp pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I need to install 2 Google Analytics counters to AMP pages.
Can you tell me please if my code is correct?

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics"      
src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>

<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
     "account": "UA-39707521-1"
     "account": "UA-75823543-3"
  },
"triggers": {
"trackPageview": {
  "on": "visible",
  "request": "pageview"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you write the title in english please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Google Tracking Codes on AMP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078429/multiple-google-tracking-codes-on-amp-pages)